# How do I convert a list to a generator?

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I have a function which returns a list of tuples, that I would like to iterate through:

```
def get_parameter_product(num_parameters, lower_range, upper_range):
    param_lists = [ xrange(lower_range, upper_range) for _ in xrange(num_parameters)]   
    return list(itertools.product(*param_lists))

for p in get_parameter_product(3, 0, 5):
    print p,

(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), ... , (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)
```

However, for larger values of num_parameters is take a lot of memory to allocate. Is it possible to convert this to a generator?

Comment: itertools.product is a generator ... so just dont call list on it. .. I think at least

Comment: Also, have a look at the documentation for `itertools.product`, to see the equivalent Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` is already a generator. You can just return it instead of converting it to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is adding an extraneous step that is not needed.

```
prod_list = get_parameter_product(3, 0, 5)
```

can be replaced with

```
prod_genr = product(range(0, 5), repeat=3)
```

Anything in `itertools` returns a generator rather than `list` or `tuple`. You may wish to look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to check you really want `product` as opposed to `combinations` or `permutations`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert a list to a generator—just don't convert your generators into lists.

First, to build up `param_lists`, use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, and you'll have an iterator instead of a list.

Second, don't call `list` in the `return` statement.

```
>>> def get_parameter_product(num_parameters, lower_range, upper_range):
...     param_lists = (xrange(lower_range, upper_range) for _ in xrange(num_parameters))
...     return itertools.product(*param_lists)
>>> p = get_parameter_product(3, 0, 5)
>>> print(p)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x101d650f0>
>>> print(list(p))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), ... , (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```